# Galleria scaling error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, galleria

I am using galleria with the flickr plugin but it is not displaying the images correctly, weirdly some of them display fine and others are scaled and the right and left or top and bottom are cut of.. how can I change this

Here is the HTML for the actual galleria on the page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>

      <style>

           /* Demo styles */
            html,body{background:#222;margin:0;}
            body{border-top:4px solid #000;}
            .content{color:#777;font:12px/1.4 "helvetica neue",arial,sans-serif;width:840px;margin:20px auto;}
            h1{font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#ddd;margin:0;}
            p{margin:0 0 20px}
            a {color:#22BCB9;text-decoration:none;}
            .cred{margin-top:20px;font-size:11px;}

            /* This rule is read by Galleria to define the gallery height: */
            #galleria{height:620px;}
        </style>

        <!-- load jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- load Galleria -->
        <script src="http://www.levencruisingclub.com/sites/all/libraries/galleria/galleria.js"></script>

        <!-- load flickr plugin -->
        <script src="http://www.levencruisingclub.com/sites/all/libraries/galleria/plugins/flickr/galleria.flickr.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="content">

        <!-- Adding gallery images. This is just a container for the dynamic flickr images -->

        <div id="galleria"></div>

        <p class="cred">Made by <a href="http://galleria.aino.se">Galleria</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <script>

    // Load the classic theme
    Galleria.loadTheme('/sites/all/libraries/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js');

        // Initialize Galleria

   $('#galleria').galleria({
    flickr: 'group:87072910@N00',

});
flickrOptions:({
    max: 100,
    size: 'big',
    sort: 'date-posted-asc'
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [imageCrop](http://galleria.io/docs/1.2/options/imageCrop/) option:

```
{
    imageCrop: false
}
```